# Align TextBlock inside a ListBoxItem

Tags: windows-phone-7, textblock, listboxitem, text-alignment

I'm developing a **Windows Phone 7** application.

I want to center vertically a textblock inside a ListBoxItem. Here is my XAML code:

```
<ListBoxItem x:Name="SingleGameItem" Height="79" Margin="10,5">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="31" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="431" TextAlignment="Center"/>
</ListBoxItem>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What happens when you use the XAML you've posted?

Comment: Have you tried setting `VerticalContentAlignment` to `Center` on the ListBox or the ListBoxItem itself?

Comment: TextBlock is vertically aligment at top of ListBoxItem.

Comment: I've found the problem (my problem). Sorry. You can see it at my answer. I've added VerticalAlignment="Center" to ListBoxItem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Options" Margin="12,8,8,8" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListBoxItem x:Name="SingleGameItem" Height="79" Margin="10,5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="31" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="431" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Sorry.